# Failing to deploy apollo graphql serverless function with clould firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, graphql, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use Apollo graphql serverless with cloud firebase, however I am stuck with one issue & cannot able to find it solution.

When I run `firebase serve`, my application runs fine and I can able to run my query on graphql playground, however when I execute `firebase deploy` command it throws an error:

> Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:graphql

I have checked many resources where the implementation is same as I am doing but still error accruing.
Is there any special thing to take care while executing the firebase deploy command?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express')
const {ApolloServer, gql} = require('apollo-server-express')

const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey.json')

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});


const typeDefs = gql`
    type Post {
        text: String
    } 

    type Query {
       post: [Post] 
    }
`

const resolvers = {
    Query : {
        post: () => {
            const arr = [{'text' : 'hello'},{'text' : 'hie'}]
            return arr
        }
    }
}

const app = express()
const server = new ApolloServer({typeDefs, resolvers})

server.applyMiddleware({app, path: "/", cors: true})

exports.graphql = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

logs

```
[2020-07-22T08:18:52.179Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 22 Jul 2020 08:18:50 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-25=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-07-22T08:18:54.181Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/ZmlyLWJhc2ljcy05OS91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hcGkvMHN4TEhkamJFblE  

[2020-07-22T08:18:54.505Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 22 Jul 2020 08:18:53 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-25=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-07-22T08:18:56.529Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/ZmlyLWJhc2ljcy05OS91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hcGkvMHN4TEhkamJFblE  

[2020-07-22T08:18:56.835Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 22 Jul 2020 08:18:55 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-25=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
[2020-07-22T08:18:58.860Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/operations/ZmlyLWJhc2ljcy05OS91cy1jZW50cmFsMS9hcGkvMHN4TEhkamJFblE  

[2020-07-22T08:18:59.189Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 {"content-type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","vary":"X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding","date":"Wed, 22 Jul 2020 08:18:57 GMT","server":"ESF","cache-control":"private","x-xss-protection":"0","x-frame-options":"SAMEORIGIN","x-content-type-options":"nosniff","alt-svc":"h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-27=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-25=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-T050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=\":443\"; ma=2592000,quic=\":443\"; ma=2592000; v=\"46,43\"","accept-ranges":"none","transfer-encoding":"chunked"}
!  functions[api(us-central1)]: Deployment error. 
Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        graphql


To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only functions:api


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Comment: "*deploy had errors*" - doesn't it log *which* errors it had?

Comment: Hi Bergi, I have added the error logs.  Using **firebase --debug  deploy --only functions** command for deploying functions

Comment: This can be caused by numerous reasons. I would make sure that I use the latest version of Firebase Tools and I would also check the logs as being suggested from the error message. Please provide us with log entries that could cause the issue in order to try and troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks @tzovourn for your support I have resolved this issue, after referring this article https://medium.com/@sandun.isuru/how-to-deploy-nodejs-express-app-to-firebase-as-function-31515c304e70                                                                    
Actually the issue was on firebase side, there is an issue with node 10 so I made a change in my package.json i.e from "engines": { "node":"10"} to "engines": { "node":"8"} and also moved all devdependicies to dependicies.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @tzovourn for your support I have resolved this issue, after referring this article https://medium.com/@sandun.isuru/how-to-deploy-nodejs-express-app-to-firebase-as-function-31515c304e70
Actually the issue was on firebase side, there is an issue with node 10 so I made a change in my package.json i.e from "engines": { "node":"10"} to "engines": { "node":"8"} and also moved all devdependicies to dependicies.